# Reset USB port power with Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, usb

I have an USB equipment that stops working when my computer reboots. The only solution is to kill the power of the port. Is there a command in the Windows Prompt that can kill the USB power?

Any tip will be very helpful,

Thanks

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/715888/how-to-control-power-to-usb-ports-using-batch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[devcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707(v=vs.85).aspx) (Windows Device Console) has commands available for enabling/disabling devices.

Here's an example: [Enable/disable a device from the command line](http://ccm.net/faq/1886-enable-disable-a-device-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It was exactly what I wanted :)